Can someone tell me how to proof this/tell me if this is even possible to proof
I got bored in maths class and came up with this theorem, can someone tell me how to prove it/if it's even possible to prove it at all?
Assuming $n$ is a perfect number
If you order the divisors of $n$, from smallest to largest, and count to the Mersenne prime in that sequence (let's call the Mersenne prime $x$), all previous divisors before $x$, will be present as divisors in all subsequent perfect numbers, along with $x+1$
Take $28$ (the second perfect number) and $496$ (the third perfect number) as examples
The proper divisors of $28$ are: $1, 2, 4, 7, 14$
The proper divisors of $496$ are: $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248$
The first prime number in the proper divisors of $28$ is $7$, and the preceding divisors are $1, 2$ and $4$, all of which are divisors of $496$ as well, additionally, $8$ is also present, which is the first prime number among the proper divisors of $28$ ($7$) plus $1$ $(7+1=8)$.
I tested this up until the $8$th perfect number, at which point my calculator ceased functioning.
Thx y'all

This is hard to follow.  The first prime number in the list of proper divisors of $28$ is $2$, of course.  The first proper divisor of any number is always prime.

Mb, I'll fix that

The only prime divisors of an (even) perfect number are $2$ and the Mersenne prime associated with the perfect number.  What are you asking?

Just asking if it's A) Accurate, and B) Where I can read more abt this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid–Euler_theorem

More about what?  Perhaps you are unaware that even perfect numbers have a complete description, see this for instance.  From that description, it follows at once that the powers of $2$ are strictly increasing.

This conjecture is unknown to be true or false.
It is known to be true if we restrict to only even perfect numbers. That is, the Euclid-Euler theorem states that all even perfect numbers have the form $2^{p-1}~(2^p - 1)$ where $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime. It follows that the  nth even perfect number $E_n$ is divisible by more powers of two than the n–1th even perfect number $E_{n-1}$, and that the first non-power-of-two factor of $E_n$ is the Mersenne prime, from which your conjecture follows. And indeed, incrementing the Mersenne prime by 1 gives $2^p$ which will be divisible by $2^{p-1}$ as well.
If there exists an odd perfect number, it will not be divisible by any of these powers of 2 and will form a counterexample to your general conjecture. But it is not known whether there are any odd perfect numbers. I would not recommend using your calculator to check for them: we know from exhaustive checking that a lower bound for odd perfect numbers is $10^{1500}$ which will probably extra overflow your calculator!

FWIW, it is currently unknown whether an odd perfect number can be divisible by a Mersenne prime.
